# Android VideoView Full Screen in Portrait Orientation

Tags: android, android-videoview

Please help me with video view full screen in portrait mode.I want to display a video in full screen at splash page for an app.

This is my code.
I have a video view which fills the width but height is only a part of screen at the middle.I want the video view to fill the whole width and height.

```
public class SplashFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = SplashFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private FragmentInterface mFragmentInterface;
private VideoView mSplashVideoView;
private Uri mUri;

public SplashFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mFragmentInterface = (FragmentInterface) context;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mFragmentInterface = null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mFragmentInterface.showActionBar(false);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    initView(view);
    initListener();
    playVideo();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    playVideo();
}

private void initView(View view) {
    mSplashVideoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.splashVideoView);
    mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getApplication().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.mylawmp4);
    mSplashVideoView.setMediaController(null);
    mSplashVideoView.setVideoURI(mUri);
}

private void initListener() {
    mSplashVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            displayScreens();
        }
    });
}

private void playVideo() {
    mSplashVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    mSplashVideoView.start();
}

private void displayScreens() {
    if (mFragmentInterface != null) {
        if (!PreferenceUtil.isLoggedIn(getActivity())) {
            mFragmentInterface.action(Constants.FragmentInterfaceConstants.ACTION_SEND_OTP, null);
        } else {
            mFragmentInterface.action(Constants.FragmentInterfaceConstants.ACTION_HOME, null);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Xml layout looks like the below

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/splashScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/splashVideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible" /> </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: try this: 
`android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following attributes to your `VideoView` in your xml layout:

```
 <VideoView 
     android:id="@+id/splashVideoView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

Comment: Hey I have a doubt ...The video seems to be stretched.Can we do something about that or should i ask the design team to provide a video with different proportions to fit different screen.

Comment: Ask your design team to provide you Portrait video(Vertical video).

Answer (score 0):

well, i think you have to edit your manifest file and add a bit of code there :

"i hope this works "

Comment: <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">